# Does there exist Git commit policies? E.g. when and what to commit?

Tags: git

We are going to use Git where I work, and we have some in house programmers, and some external freelance programmers that have never used Source Control Management before.

The reason we want to use Git is to be better at communicating with the freelance programmers, and to avoid code from being lost and in general track what they do.

So now we need a commit policy. I.e when should users commit, and when should they rebase commits and so on.

Does there exist written policies from other projects that I can read?

Or does someone know of good practices that we should use?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598743/what-git-workflow-to-use-for-2-non-co-located-developers

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466141/how-are-you-structuring-your-git-repository-workflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is designed to be as flexible as possible in this regard. However, there are some common deployment models. A good overview can be found in the [ProGit Workflow](http://progit.org/book/ch5-1.html) section.